# Creating polygon from visible map extent using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, extents, data-frame

Is there a way to create a polygon using the visible extent of a data frame in ModelBuilder?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no geo-processing tool that I'm aware of that can access the data frame properties so you need to write a bit of python and expose that to your model as a script tool.

This question was answered over 4 years ago over on the ESRI forum. The link to this page is [here](https://geonet.esri.com/message/226898#226898).